# Swift nil Optional String = Empty String

Tags: string, swift, struct, option-type

This one does not make sense to me at all.  I have a struct that takes a few strings:

```
public struct Organization {
  let id: String
  let name: String
  let legacyID: String?
  let rID: String?

  public init(id: String, name: String, legacyID: String?, rID: String?) {
    self.id = id
    self.name = name
    self.legacyID = legacyID
    self.rID = rID
  }
}
```

Notice that `legacyID` and `rID` are optional.  However, if I attempt to set either of them to `nil` or `.None`, instead they get set to `""`(empty string).  Ex:

```
let org = Organization(id: company.companyID, name: company.name, legacyID: company.context, rID: nil)
```

And yet, when I attempt to access `rID`, it shows up as `""` instead of `nil`.  I've even tried directly setting `nil` in the `init` and it's still set as `""`.  This is messing up my equality checks.  Anyone know what is going on?

Note: This is Swift 1.2

Comment: I can't reproduce this behavior. Can you post the entire code that demonstrates this?

Comment: No, I really can't.. at least not right now. I can't repro in a small standalone project and I'm pretty sure my employer would fire me if I posted their entire codebase... not to mention it's 10's of thousands of lines of code!

Comment: @mattt I am using Modules/Dynamic Frameworks though... and the Organization is defined in a module, but set in the "main" app.  Is it possible this is the cause?  I'm grasping at straws here.  I've worked around the issue but it bothers me that it's there.

Comment: I'm not asking for your code base. Just enough to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Yeah, sorry.  Under some time pressure, and I couldn't repro in a smaller project anyway.  But the issue continues to persist in the main project.  However, I've learned it was the debugger that was faulty.  The actual code was producing correct results when I used `println` instead of printing from the debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out the problem was the debugger.  If I used the debugger to check the value, even in the debugger prompt, `p/po/print org.rID` it returned the incorrect value.  However, inserting a `println(org.rID)` in my code printed the correct value `nil`.  I hate it when I can't trust the debugger.  Happened when they switched from `gcd` to `lldb` too.  Hopefully this is straightened out in Xcode 7.

Answer (score 1):

You getting "" as output because your data type is String. So if any String variable is empty or nil it always shows "". You can't get nil as output by using String type. Even if you assign nil directly nothing happen same output will come.

Edited :
This is what i got from ur code. Its working properly.
[image]

Comment: But my data type isn't `String`, it's `String?`, which is an Optional.  So setting the value to `nil` or `.None` should work.

Comment: Check my edited answer. Your code seems like working properly. Check the way you accessing is correct.